# What SPSS test should I use for blood pressure pre- and post-intervention for comparison?

Tags: t-test, spss, paired-data, software

I have 10 participants who consumed an intervention for 3 weeks. 
I would like to look at any significance between pre-intervention and post-intervention readings. 
What SPSS test should I use?

I have tried doing a Paired samples t-test because it's the same sample at 2 different times but got confused on which data to place in variable boxes.

This is because I have 4 sets of data: mean systolic before, mean systolic after, mean diastolic before, mean diastolic after for each of the 10 participants.

If Paired T-test is correct, would it make sense to do this:

Pair 1: Variable 1 (systolic before) -- Variable 2 (systolic after)

Pair 2: Varible 1 (diastolic before) -- Variable 2 (diastolic after)

Comment: Yes, if it makes conceptual sense to interpret SBP and DBP separately. You may also consider Mean Arterial Pressure ([MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_arterial_pressure)).

Comment: Judging the usefulness of an intervention based on only 10 participants is problematic. To what population would you refer when discussing results? Is this the same situation posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403699/spss-paired-samples-t-test-outcome-interpretation/403705#403705)?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight Thank you,  I will look into Mean Arterial Pressure

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your response. Yes it is an issue but, unfortunately, I am a student and could only recruit a certain number especially due to university budget. I would refer to female university students. Yes it is the same situation; I decided to create a separate thread to not cause confusion :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Answer (score 1):

You were correct that the paired sample t-test was what you wanted. However, you can only test a single outcome at a time. You are running into problems because you are attempting to test two different outcomes (systolic and diastolic pressure).

[Penguin_Knight](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/13047/penguin-knight) suggested one solution in the comments: use a single measure which incorporates both, such as mean arterial pressure. I don't know anything about the health field, but the idea of moving to a single new measure which unifies the previous two makes sense.

Alternatively, you could test either systolic or diastolic pressure independently, or run two different t-tests.

Which should you pick? The one that fits your hypothesis!  A statistical test is based on a hypothesis about what you think should happen. Is your hypothesis about diastolic or systolic pressure? If so, then you should use whichever your hypothesis includes.